# How to output names of ruby unit tests

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I have a unit test (example is modified [Test::Unit documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/classes/Test/Unit.html))

```
require 'test/unit'

class TC_MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_something
    assert(true)
  end
end
```

When I execute it, I get:

```
Loaded suite C:/test
Started
.
Finished in 0.0 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

I would like to get something like this (`test_something` is outputted):

```
Loaded suite C:/test
Started
test_something
.
Finished in 0.0 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run unit test with [verbose](http://spattendesign.com/2007/10/11/ruby-unit-test-command-line-options) option.

```
test.rb -v v
```

or

```
test.rb --verbose=verbose
```

Output:

```
Loaded suite C:/test
Started
test_something(TC_MyTest): .

Finished in 0.0 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

Comment: You don't need the =verbose after the --verbose, or the v after -v... just running with -v or --verbose will do the trick.

Answer (score 17):

If you're testing in rails you can use

```
rake test TESTOPTS=-v
```

Answer (score 4):

Command line options do not work if you are creating your own test runner:

```
Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(TC_MyTest)
```

You will have to specify verbosity in test runner. [Test::Unit::UI options](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Test/Unit/UI.html) are:

SILENT = 0, PROGRESS_ONLY = 1, NORMAL = 2, VERBOSE = 3.

So, for verbose:

```
Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(TC_MyTest, 3)
```