# How can I see what actually happens when a Test::Unit test runs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

In a Rails application I have a Test::Unit functional test that's failing, but the output on the console isn't telling me much.

How can I view the request, the response, the flash, the session, the variables set, and so on?

Is there something like...

```
rake test specific_test_file --verbose
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add puts statements to your test case as suggested, or add calls to Rails.logger.debug() to your application code and watch your log/development.log to trace through what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

In your test you have access to a bunch of resources you can user to debug your test.

```
 p @request
 p @response
 p @controller
 p flash
 p cookie
 p session
```

Also, remember that your action should be as simple as possibile and all the specific action execution should be tested by single Unit test.
Functional test should be reserved to the the overall action execution.

What does it mean in practice? If something doesn't work in your action, and your action calls 3 Model methods, you should be able to easily isolate the problem just looking at the unit tests. If one (or more) unit test fails, then you know which method is the guilty.
If all the unit tests pass, then the problem is the action itself but it should be quite easy to debug since you already tested the methods separately.

Answer (score 1):

in the failing test use `p @request` etc.  its ugly, but it can work

Answer (score 0):

An answer to a separate question [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427451/how-to-output-names-of-ruby-unit-tests/428435#428435)

```
rake test TESTOPTS=-v
```

Answer (score 0):

The slick way is to use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry/) and [pry-nav](https://github.com/nixme/pry-nav) gems. Be sure to include them in your test gem group. I use them in the development group as well. The great thing about pry and pry nav is you can step through your code with a console, so you can not only see the code as it's executed, but you can also enter console commands during the test.

You just enter binding.pry in the places in the code you want to trigger the console. Then using the 'step' command, you can move line by line through the code as it's executed.