# Creating a test report using Ruby unit test

Tags: ruby, testunit, rest-client

I have a working testsuite which tests some RESTful API's.  Up until now the stdout results have been fine:

```
.......E..F..
```

However now I need something a bit more informative.

The output should be:

```
TestName, startTime, endTime, Result
```

I'll probably write this to a file in csv or xml.  Now, I'm having no problems with the test name, start time and end time (multiple ways to do this) but I don't know how to write the result, the . or F or E to the file.

Is there any way I can extract the test result and do something with it within the test or test runner?

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try the verbose option. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427451/how-to-output-names-of-ruby-unit-tests

Comment: Okay that is a help.  Now I have a new problem of getting the start and finish times in there!

Comment: Actually it's still not really what I want.  I need to be able to write the result to a file in a format I can control

Comment: `$stdout = File.open('yourfile.txt', 'w+')`

Comment: You may want to check if there's a gem that already does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative - simple - is to work with the output provided using command line string manipulation tools (sed/awk/..) and generate the required output format.

A more involved alternative would be to dig into the [test-unit internals](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit) and create your own test-runner which gives the required output. The [./lib/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/blob/master/lib/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb) file would be a good place to start.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558600/429758 for an example of how to write a customized test runner.